# Kafka JMX missing data

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, jmx-exporter

I have two kafka cluster each one exporting metrics via JMX and prometheus. Some data are missing from one of the deployment. I add that both configuration for JMX or for Logging looks the same, and my test clients are also the same. I can't attach image so I'll try to describe what I see in Jconsole:

When I'm connected directly to the JMX port I have:
**on the left :**

**kafka.server**

- **Fetch**

  - Attributes

    - queue-siez
  - FETCH

    - Attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time
- **Produce**

  - Attributes

    - queue-siez
  - PRODUCE

    - Attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time

**On the right:**

**kafka.server**

- **Fetch**

  - Attributes

    - queue-siez
  - CN%3Dbroker-connect

    - attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time
  - perf-user

    - attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time
- **Produce**

  - Attributes

    - queue-siez
  - CN%3Dbroker-connect

    - attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time
  - perf-user

    - attributes

      - byte-rate
      - trhottle-time

So in the right JMX we can see that we have the detail for each of my connected clients (MTLS or OAUTH clients) but on the left nothing. I guess that I can see the global value of byte-rate for all produce request but I can't see each clients. Does someone have a clue on what can cause that difference ?

Comment: I can't tell what you're showing. But are you running `kafka-console-producer` on one of the machines, and not the other? That's the only reason you'd see producer/user metrics at all

Comment: Multiple clients are running on this kafka. On the side I have kafka connect and schema registry that are also by default kafka clients.

Comment: Okay, well, ideally clients, connect, nor the registry should run on any broker. But even if they did, you should see JMX metrics from all of them. And no part of your listed metrics here show mTLS or Oauth, so it's unclear what you mean by that